# Problem about python smime signature verifying

Tags: python, cryptography

our service is running python, and suddenly i cant verify the java-signed signature from others.

i try verifying in java, it works...

it just suddenly happened without doing any change to code and cert file

and partner also claimed that they've changed nothing

here's java code, it returns true

```
public static boolean verifySignature(String rawMsg, final String signedMsg, X509Certificate certificate) {
        try {
            if (Security.getProvider("BC") == null) {
                Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
            }
            CMSProcessableByteArray digestContent = new CMSProcessableByteArray(rawMsg.getBytes());

            CMSSignedData Signed = new CMSSignedData(digestContent, Base64.getDecoder().decode(signedMsg.getBytes()));
            SignerInformation Signer = (SignerInformation) Signed.getSignerInfos().getSigners().iterator().next();
            return Signer.verify(certificate, "BC");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (Security.getProvider("BC") == null)
            Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        String publicKey = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\r\n" + 
                "MIICWDCCAcGgAwIBAgIJANlZ7YIVy5L8MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMEUxCzAJBgNV\r\n" + 
                "BAYTAkFVMRMwEQYDVQQIDApTb21lLVN0YXRlMSEwHwYDVQQKDBhJbnRlcm5ldCBX\r\n" + 
                "aWRnaXRzIFB0eSBMdGQwHhcNMTgxMjA4MDIyNzQzWhcNMTkxMjA4MDIyNzQzWjBF\r\n" + 
                "MQswCQYDVQQGEwJBVTETMBEGA1UECAwKU29tZS1TdGF0ZTEhMB8GA1UECgwYSW50\r\n" + 
                "ZXJuZXQgV2lkZ2l0cyBQdHkgTHRkMIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKB\r\n" + 
                "gQDwhejRDjKm80CTtaQvCHnaifscZVM37UkJxy7b++wi842yiyN4kVBvfZ9OHH8H\r\n" + 
                "isO7tfIG2ofn2TKdqWbepCYvq6TQ0/AQAahpJTTktFGUE7eWiABqxCZctnv3STe3\r\n" + 
                "Yj8PywEsjLTxbqGXhj5xZwQjGE5DNpRdwmbemANiZmrKYwIDAQABo1AwTjAdBgNV\r\n" + 
                "HQ4EFgQUK3guJRzCAJGpOOnwG+AeWAxVJmUwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUK3guJRzCAJGp\r\n" + 
                "OOnwG+AeWAxVJmUwDAYDVR0TBAUwAwEB/zANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFAAOBgQAgBsyA\r\n" + 
                "Pl6NHdiJphVZsJoYV1185kS4+e4sVXjwohWRWfEboxdv7s4uZ9Bw792cgrWG3TPn\r\n" + 
                "Z2Lzg5Y+CjtPGrd7Yc2vC+xUVv+Roj+X3QYCCn5z8peJXTK2xlsydWlV0pzlJDuX\r\n" + 
                "pirVw+4A51cbyc3orGrmldU0U9GN9N2wn1p10g==\r\n" + 
                "-----END CERTIFICATE-----\r\n" + 
                "";
        String msg = "{\"transactionInfo\":{\"cRefNum\":\"ocbtest191210000001\",\"clientCode\":\"Airpay\",\"pRefNum\":\"5def621cb91b43440905caf8f9dd59ed\",\"transactionReturn\":\"100\",\"transactionReturnMsg\":\"Account is not yet linked system or invalid data\"}}";
        System.out.println(msg);
        String signature = "MIIBKgYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIIBGzCCARcCAQExCzAJBgUrDgMCGgUAMAsGCSqGSIb3DQEHATGB9zCB9AIBATBSMEUxCzAJBgNVBAYTAkFVMRMwEQYDVQQIDApTb21lLVN0YXRlMSEwHwYDVQQKDBhJbnRlcm5ldCBXaWRnaXRzIFB0eSBMdGQCCQDZWe2CFcuS/DAJBgUrDgMCGgUAMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUABIGAGZnn9GZS80RHtseXsewKCR8gKJ9UvfrNUH1LzYnr5rUClpSSE9dN+ZB2oORUstAtKcvS4j9UHQYel5ooGvzYa+1LlnX12LwfVYAOXecMz2ZT0GUaAfmPyPRYg+rsc63SgPzVIDHAT7Va5EJ6JUx+qncP14f4AeUmEyJfbIff5ro=";

        CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509", "BC");
        X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) certFactory.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(publicKey.getBytes()));
        System.out.println("Verify: " + CryptographyUtils.verifySignature(msg, signature, certificate));
    }
```

and here's the python code, almost from the sample code in docs

```
def pkcs7_verify(cert_path, raw_data, signature):
    sig = '\n'.join(chunk_string(signature, 64))
    out = '''MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/signed; protocol="application/x-pkcs7-signature"; micalg="sha-256"; boundary="----"

This is an S/MIME signed message

------
%s
------
Content-Type: application/x-pkcs7-signature; name="smime.p7s"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7s"

%s

--------''' % (raw_data, sig)
    # print out
    # Instantiate an SMIME object.
    s = SMIME.SMIME()

    # Load the signer's cert.
    x509 = X509.load_cert(cert_path)
    sk = X509.X509_Stack()
    sk.push(x509)
    s.set_x509_stack(sk)

    # Load the signer's CA cert. In this case, because the signer's
    # cert is self-signed, it is the signer's cert itself.
    st = X509.X509_Store()
    st.load_info(cert_path)
    s.set_x509_store(st)

    # Load the data, verify it.
    try:
        p7_bio = BIO.MemoryBuffer(out)
        p7, data_bio = SMIME.smime_load_pkcs7_bio(p7_bio)
        v = s.verify(p7, p7_bio)
    except Exception:
        import traceback
        traceback.print_exc()
        return False
    return True
```

it just raise

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxx/Develop/python/scripts/sign.py", line 46, in pkcs7_verify
    v = s.verify(p7, p7_bio)
  File "/Users/xxx/.virtualenvs/giro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/M2Crypto/SMIME.py", line 262, in verify
    data_bio._ptr(), flags)
PKCS7_Error: certificate verify error
```

new cert

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIChDCCAe2gAwIBAgIJAK/KaxzV02sPMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMFsxCzAJBgNV
BAYTAlZOMQwwCgYDVQQIDANIQ00xFDASBgNVBAcMC0hvIENoaSBNaW5oMQwwCgYD
VQQKDANPQ0IxDDAKBgNVBAsMA09DQjEMMAoGA1UEAwwDT0NCMB4XDTE5MTIxMzA2
NTY1OVoXDTI0MTIxMTA2NTY1OVowWzELMAkGA1UEBhMCVk4xDDAKBgNVBAgMA0hD
TTEUMBIGA1UEBwwLSG8gQ2hpIE1pbmgxDDAKBgNVBAoMA09DQjEMMAoGA1UECwwD
T0NCMQwwCgYDVQQDDANPQ0IwgZ8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADgY0AMIGJAoGBAPCF
6NEOMqbzQJO1pC8IedqJ+xxlUzftSQnHLtv77CLzjbKLI3iRUG99n04cfweKw7u1
8gbah+fZMp2pZt6kJi+rpNDT8BABqGklNOS0UZQTt5aIAGrEJly2e/dJN7diPw/L
ASyMtPFuoZeGPnFnBCMYTkM2lF3CZt6YA2JmaspjAgMBAAGjUDBOMB0GA1UdDgQW
BBQreC4lHMIAkak46fAb4B5YDFUmZTAfBgNVHSMEGDAWgBQreC4lHMIAkak46fAb
4B5YDFUmZTAMBgNVHRMEBTADAQH/MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAA4GBANzvwH3Hs5Av
iuK4MK3lUScfmShusdHCDHYh+boF7TIQNW9f1fJijNnHOk92antONyZYCcfhiiT0
6bpok9XtpAnYurNI4nimQPhb2/kBKyW2xhmLEbRD2QAzXiw85qF6yTOqjsOKgqHP
fenzMFLsJRRVcNe89cs2kC1qMP2zure+
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The certificate *expired* a few days ago (`Dec 8 02:27:43 2019 GMT`). The following OpenSSl-statement, [[1]](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/x509.html):

```
openssl x509 -enddate -noout -in <path to certificate>
```

results in:

```
notAfter=Dec 8 02:27:43 2019 GMT
```

That's probably what's causing the issue.  It also fits into the picture that no code changes have been made. Both codes seem to deal differently with an expired certificate. If in the Java-code, [[2]](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html#checkValidity()):

```
certificate.checkValidity();
```

is added, the verification also fails due to a corresponding exception, [[3]](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/security/cert/CertificateExpiredException.html):

```
CertificateExpiredException: certificate expired on 20191208022743GMT+00:00
```

Comment: hello, do u know why it raise 
'PKCS7_Error: signer certificate not found'
now?...sr, im not an expert in ssl, i searched about it and got no idea...
i've pasted the new cert

Comment: I can't answer that off the top of my head. Possibly a self-signed certificate that isn't in the trusted root CA store? If that doesn't help or you get stuck, please post a new question so that the problem can be analyzed in more detail.